# Exceed the amount of parameters in a method

Tags: java, avro

I am using Apache Avro tool to generate schema class from .avsc file. Running into an issue where I have more than 300 fields in my AVRO schema, which causes "Java Error: too many parameters" when using this class. (Because each field in my schema will be one parameter in my schema class constructor). Java has a limit of 255 parameters in a method.

I know I may be able to resolve this issue by using generic record (instead of Avro Tool and class generation). But before I restructured my whole thing, is there any workaround?

Comment: More than 255 parameters to a constructor? What needs fixing here is the design, I'd say...

Answer (score 1):

Your schema design is pretty bad if a table (class) has 300 fields.

Find some way to break the data down into multiple classes and multiple tables.

Reading up on [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) would be a good start.

Comment: I am using Google bigQuery, big schema table is more efficient than multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

You should really reevaluate your design if your data has that many fields. How would your code look when a consumer tried to construct an object of this type?

> is there any workaround?

No, the [JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10) says this:

> The number of method parameters is limited to 255 by the definition of
>   a method descriptor (§4.3.3), where the limit includes one unit for
>   this in the case of instance or interface method invocations. Note
>   that a method descriptor is defined in terms of a notion of method
>   parameter length in which a parameter of type long or double
>   contributes two units to the length, so parameters of these types
>   further reduce the limit.